# How to treat such a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a request in python and a Response Looks as following:

```
{'items': [{'creation_date': datetime.date(2019, 5, 10),
            'description': 'bla',
            'duration': 1216,
            'id': 1002,
            'is_copy_of': None,
            'last_update_date': datetime.date(2019, 5, 15),
            'name': 'Fablenk'},
           {'creation_date': datetime.date(2019, 5, 15),
            'description': 'blablabla ',
            'duration': 1216,
            'id': 1002,
            'is_copy_of': None,
            'last_update_date': datetime.date(2019, 5, 15),
            'name': 'Fablenk'}]}
```

If I want to work only with the first element in the list, I'd command `list[0]` but this is not a case here. How do I recall each single lists' element here, such that I can do some actions with each of them?

Comment: why can't you do `response.items[0]`?

Comment: Thanks! It helped!

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to work with the whole list, you can use `response['items']`.
- If you want to work with the particular dict, you can use `response['items'][index]`, for example `response['items'][0]`
- If you want to work with every dict in the list, you can use generator: `[do_something_with(each_dict) for each_dict in response['items']]`
- If you want to work with the particular dict element in each dict, you can extend the generator: `[do_something_with(each_dict['creation_date']) for each_dict in response['items']]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Was searching for these curly brakets for a Long time

Comment: @anastasiiia They are called `dict` (dictionary)

Comment: and if I want to get some particular value, say id, can I write something like response.items[i].get('id')? The program says that I can't...

Comment: `response['items'][i]['id']`

Comment: Somehow I get a message that object is not subscriptable..pffff... and Internet says that These objects are kinbd of in a Container. How can I Access single Elements as id then?

Comment: You are trying to get element from non-dict structure.